# Select data in a text file from a separate list - perl or unix

Tags: perl, unix, text-processing, csv

I have a massive tab delimited file like this:

> contig04733 contig00012 77
>  contig00546 contig01344 12
>   contig08943 contig00001 14
>  contig00765 contig03125 88
>  etc

And I have a separate tab delimited file with only a subset of these contig pairs like this:

> contig04733 contig00012
>  contig08943 contig00001
>  etc

I want to extract into a new file the lines in the first file that correspond with the ones listed in the second. In this particular dataset I think which way round each pair should be the same in both files. But would also like to know if say:

> file1 contig08943 contig00001 14

but in file2 its

> contig00001 contig08943

and I still want that combination, is it possible to script something for this too?

My code is below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#open the contig pairs list
open (PAIRS, "$ARGV[0]") or die "Error opening the input file with contig pairs";

#hash to store contig IDs - I think?!
my $pairs;

#read through the pairs list and read into memory?
while(<PAIRS>){
    chomp $_; #get rid of ending whitepace
    $pairs->{$_} = 1;
}
close(PAIRS);

#open data file
open(DATA, "$ARGV[1]") or die "Error opening the sequence pairs file\n";
while(<DATA>){
    chomp $_;
    my ($contigs, $identity) = split("\t", $_);
    if (defined $pairs->{$contigs}) {
        print STDOUT "$_\n";
    }
}
close(DATA);
```

Comment: Also if possible, I would like to convert the 3rd column in the first file - dividing the number by 100 and then square rooting it. eg. the first line of the new file in this example would be contig04733 contig00012 0.877

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried?

Comment: @GregBacon - trying this:

use strict;
use warnings;

#open the contig pairs list
open (PAIRS, "$ARGV[0]") or die "Error opening the input file with contig pairs";

#hash to store contig IDs - I think?!
my $pairs;

#read through the pairs list and read into memory?
while(<PAIRS>){
 chomp $_; #get rid of ending whitepace
 $pairs->{$_} = 1;
}
close(PAIRS);


#open data file
open(DATA, "$ARGV[1]") or die "Error opening the sequence pairs file\n";

while(<DATA>){
 chomp $_;
 
 my ($contigs, $identity) = split("\t", $_);
 if (defined $pairs->{$contigs}) {
  print STDOUT "$_\n";
 }
}
close(DATA);

Comment: @GregBacon but this requires me removing gap/tab between first two columns and then separating them again I think....sorry I'm completely new to perl so just trying to stitch together examples from web!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piece together the code below without the running commentary to get a working program. We start off with typical front matter that instructs `perl` to give you helpful warnings if you make common mistakes.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
```

Showing the user when necessary how to properly invoke your program is always a nice touch.

```
die "Usage: $0 master subset\n" unless @ARGV == 2;
```

With `read_subset`, the program reads the *second* file named on the command line. Because your question states that you do not care about the order, *e.g.*, that

```
contig00001    contig08943
```

is equivalent to

```
contig08943    contig00001
```

the code increments both `$subset{$p1}{$p2}` and `$subset{$p2}{$p1}`.

```
sub read_subset {
  my($path) = @_;

  my %subset;
  open my $fh, "<", $path or die "$0: open $path: $!";
  while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my($p1,$p2) = split /\t/;
    ++$subset{$p1}{$p2};
    ++$subset{$p2}{$p1};
  }

  %subset;
}
```

Using a hash to mark occurrences that your program has observed is highly frequent in Perl programs. In fact, many of the examples in the Perl FAQ use hashes named `%seen`, as in “I have *seen* this.”

By removing the second command-line argument with `pop`, that leaves only the master file which lets the program easily read all lines of input using `while (<>) { ... }`. With `%subset` populated, the code splits each line into fields and skips any line not marked seen. Everything that passes this filter is printed on the standard output.

```
my %subset = read_subset pop @ARGV;
while (<>) {
  my($f1,$f2) = split /\t/;
  next unless $subset{$f1}{$f2};
  print;
}
```

For example:

```
$ cat file1
contig04733     contig00012     77
contig00546     contig01344     12
contig08943     contig00001     14
contig00765     contig03125     88

$ cat file2
contig04733     contig00012
contig00001     contig08943

$ perl extract-subset file1 file2
contig04733     contig00012     77
contig08943     contig00001     14
```

To create a new output that contains the selected subset, redirect the standard output as in

```
$ perl extract-subset file1 file2 >my-subset
```

Comment: Thank you so much - especially for breaking it down so I can learn from it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using a hash of hashes based on the two keys (after a split)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#open the contig pairs list
open (PAIRS, "$ARGV[0]") or die "Error opening the input file with contig pairs";

#hash to store contig IDs - I think?!
#my $pairs;

#read through the pairs list and read into memory?
my %all_configs;
while(<PAIRS>){
    chomp $_; #get rid of ending whitepace
    my @parts = split("\t", $_); #split into ['contig04733', 'contig00012', 77]
    #store the entire row as a hash of hashes
    $all_configs{$parts[0]}{$parts[1]} = $_;
    #$pairs->{$_} = 1; 
}
close(PAIRS);

#open data file
open(DATA, "$ARGV[1]") or die "Error opening the sequence pairs file\n";
while(<DATA>){
    chomp $_;
    my ($contigs, $identity) = split("\t", $_);
    #see if we find a row, one way, or the other
    my $found_row = $all_configs{$contigs}{$identity} 
        || $all_configs{$identity}{$contigs};
    #if found, the split, and handle each part    
    if ($found_row) {
        my @parts = split("\t", $found_row);
        #same sequence as in first file
        my $modified_row  = $parts[0]."\t".$parts[1].(sqrt($parts[2]/100));
        #if you want to keep the same sequence as found in second file
        my $modified_row  = $contigs."\t".$identity.(sqrt($parts[2]/100));

        print STDOUT $found_row."\n"; #or
        print STDOUT $modified_row."\n";
    }
}
close(DATA);
```